# How can I use a Discord Bot to upload a PNG created by that bot to a server?

Tags: python, discord

I am attempting to use the Discord API to create a bot that will take a user's valid LaTeX input, convert the LaTeX to a PNG and then upload that PNG to the server.  I have some code that will generate the LaTeX PNG thanks to some googling, but I am stuck on the upload step.

```
def plot_equation(eq, fontsize=50, outfile=None, padding=0.1, **kwargs):
"""Plot an equation as a matplotlib figure.
Parameters
----------
eq : string
    The equation that you wish to plot. Should be plottable with
    latex. If `$` is included, they will be stripped.
fontsize : number
    The fontsize passed to plt.text()
outfile : string
    Name of the file to save the figure to.
padding : float
    Amount of padding around the equation in inches.
Returns
-------
ax : matplotlib axis
    The axis with your equation.
"""
# clean equation string
eq = eq.strip('$').replace(' ', '')

# set up figure
f = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes([0,0,1,1])    
r = f.canvas.get_renderer()

# display equation
t = ax.text(0.5, 0.5, '${}$'.format(eq), fontsize=fontsize,
    horizontalalignment='center',verticalalignment='center')

# resize figure to fit equation
bb = t.get_window_extent(renderer=r)
w,h = bb.width/f.dpi,np.ceil(bb.height/f.dpi)
f.set_size_inches((padding+w,padding+h))

# set axis limits so equation is centered
plt.xlim([0,1])
plt.ylim([0,1])
ax.grid(False)
ax.set_axis_off()


if outfile is not None:
    plt.savefig(outfile, **kwargs)

return ax
```

Generates the PNG. And in the bot portion of my project, I have

```
@client.command()
async def tex(ctx):
    image = await plot_equation(eq)
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File('path\to\file.png')
```

But I am not sure how to point to file to the 'path\to\file.png'. Any help on this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using a string path the file and it didn't work? Also you shouldn't need to `await` that call to your local `plot_equation` function.

Comment: I realized that I didn't phrase the issue I was having properly, and it turns out I was thinking too hard and confusing myself. It is not working yet, but my issue is no longer related to this specific problem. Thank you for kickstarting my brain a bit.